# Eloquent mass assignment ignoring a form input field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to insert a row to my table by mass assignment but Eloquent ignores a a SELECT field from my form.

```
public function create(Request $request, StoreNewAdRequest $formRequest) {

    $data = $request->all();
    $data["uid"] = Auth::user()->id;
    $new_ad = \App\Ad::Create($data);
}
```

I have about 30 columns, all of them gets populated except for the one in question. I have all the fillables filled in and also there is no typo in my code. The input value is typecasted to the right type in my model.

I tried to debug the query

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
dd($queries);
```

**I could not see the field name in question in my query. Eloquent query builder is just ignoring that SELECT input field.**

Also when I do

```
$my_ad->ignored_field = $request->input('ignored_field');
$my_ad->save();
```

the column in question gets populated as well, so it is not a database error.

I tried to google this issue but found nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show the form here? and Also the select statement that is not being accepted

Comment: Nevermind. I found a typo. Thanks.

Comment: If you've resolved this by a typo, please close it so it doesn't just stay open forever.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by finding a typo in my form.